# Relationship to Me error on Ancestry.com

Tags: ancestry.com

I am descended from 2 children of my 22nd great-grandmother. One of the fathers is listed as 22nd great-grandfather and the other is listed as husband 22nd great-grandmother.  Is there a way to fix the second to reflect that he is also my 22nd great=grandfather?

Answer (score 2):

Ancestry doesn't show every possible relation between yourself and another person.

> "If someone in your tree is related to you in multiple ways (for
> example, if they're your 9th cousin and they're also married to your
> aunt), the relationship on their profile page will display the
> biological relationship before a relationship through marriage, unless
> the relationship through marriage is a spouse or parent-in-law—in
> which case, the spouse or parent-in-law would be displayed first. In
> this example, your uncle would be displayed as your 9th cousin. "

You cannot control or change what is displayed.  One thing to check, however,  would be that every relationship between you and your 22x GGF is set correctly; if any relationship is set incorrectly or missing, then the "spouse first" case would kick in, as it seems to be in your particular case.

Ref: https://support.ancestry.com/s/article/View-Relationship-to-Me-in-Ancestry-Member-Trees-1460090076557